# What is the best way to get up to speed on BizTalk?

Tags: biztalk

How should an experienced .NET & SQL developer go about becoming a BizTalk expert for a project starting in 1 month? How should I spend my limited time to gain some practical skill & knowledge in BizTalk so I can "walk the talk"?

I am self employed, and would not be willing to spend more than USD300. I have the book "Professional BizTalk Server 2006" by Wrox, but have not found it to be a particularly good learning resource (very dry, needs more real world examples).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [BizTalk Virtual Labs](http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/virtual-labs.aspx) in MSDN are a pretty good place to start with. [Pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/olt/courses.aspx) also has several good BizTalk courses, and their online subscription isn't too expensive; would likely be a good option.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with everything written this far. All solid info.

I have a few addons, coming from a fellow freelancer working with BizTalk since 2002:

Unit testing.
It's not easy to do, but check out BizUnit. A Codeplex based toolset written and maintained by Kevin Smith. One of the early BizTalk heroes :-) http://bizunit.codeplex.com/

Deployment / getting things into production
But also keep in mind that none of the day to day development stuff will prepare you for the part of the project where you have to deploy the app and make sure that it is "manageable" by operations. This can be quite complex, and is a topic in it's own right. 
Check out Apress Pro BizTalk 2009, it's got a decent (IMO) chapter on this.

The entire development process around BizTalk. 
The first two chapters of the same book will give you a good impression on what a BizTalk project is about. Where to use it, and where to not use it, how to organize projects, and name your stuff.  Really a good collection of info that you would only get by reading 5-6  years of blogs back in time :-)

And one last thing. Depending on the roles on the project, you might be asked to optimize and tune BizTalk. And if they don't ask you. Make sure that you ask if others have done that, because you have to do it. BizTalk should always be tuned towards what it is supposed to do. Low latency vs high throughput, tuned according to hardware, correct setup and config of network around the SQL boxes, etc etc etc.  This can be hairy stuff, and you should be careful not to jump into it before reading up on it all. But it's a subject we as freelancers are often expected to be able to deal with ... so thought I might bring it up.

Example ... BizTalk x64 processes on an x64 box runs really bad out of the box, actually worse than on the x86 processes. The 64 bit processes need to be tuned to really use all the MEM that are availble to them.

Anyways ... a bag of mixed tips and I hope you can use some of them!  And good luck!  It can be a tough start, but if used right, BizTalk can be a great product/toolset.

And remember .... if it is ugly, or hard, or both. You are doing it wrong.  And don't be afraid to dive into .net code, and bolt it onto the BizTalk box. We all do it ... some just won't admit to it :-D

Answer (score 1):

Start with the advice of tomasr.

Then, try and build something as real as possible. Biztalk is the kind of product where everything seems fine when you read the book and follow the examples, then you sit down to do something and you are thinking "what do I do now".

Answer (score 1):

As per Thomas and Shiraz - set up an environment and get your hands dirty. If you haven't done so already, download and install [BizTalk Server 2010 Developer Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=938102b8-a677-4c20-906d-f6ae472b3a6a&displaylang=en)

But just to temper your expectation, IMHO expertise in BizTalk (or any other EAI / BPM / ESB product) can take years to accumulate.

It isn't clear whether you are developing for a client with an established BizTalk installation, or if this is the client's first BizTalk deployment. If so, one thing not to be underestimated is that the operational considerations of running a production BizTalk environment (performance, redundancy, reliability, auditing, tracking, monitoring with SCOM etc) are as complex as the development and testing - but understanding of this will be important to 'walk the talk'.

W.r.t. dev, start with some a simple EAI type mapping project, and then work your way through the [SDK samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560186%28v=BTS.70%29.aspx) progress to some common messaging patterns (e.g. batching with aggregator), and then move into the BPM type orchestrations. You can probably leave BAM and the BRE for later.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

+1 to tomasr for mentioning the virtual labs. Getting hands-on is definitely the way to go, as Shiraz Bhaiji also mentions. Hopefully you're not starting with BizTalk 2006, and can go with the latest: 2010. If that's the case, you can get the Developer Ed. of BizTalk 2010 for free now (see link from nonnb).

I'd also recommend Richard Seroter's book: 'SOA Patterns with BizTalk Server 2009'  ([available on Amazon.com](http://amzn.to/gsu3me)). There are many ways to do the "wrong" things with BizTalk, and this book does an excellent job of walking through both the how and the why of building BizTalk solutions (with the code samples available from [the publisher's site](https://www.packtpub.com/support?nid=4189)). And yes, it pretty much takes a whole book to go through it all. It's a good (more readable) companion to the Pro BizTalk 20xx series (which is generally better for very specific questions/tasks).

Comment: The SOA Patterns with BizTalk is now in it's second edition. https://www.packtpub.com/networking-and-servers/soa-patterns-biztalk-server-2013-second-edition   (Full Disclosure: I'm a co-author on this book)